# Console application, How do I make Console.ReadLine() IF/ELSE Statements?

Tags: c#, console-application

I was making a tool named "Ferna".. And I was trying to make different commands on it, but the problem is that these "commands" have to be in order, like when I try to execute a command, I have to execute them in order.. But I want it like it doesn't have to be in order so if i write "cyan" it executes it, it doesn't have to wait for the 5th `ReadLine()`

**Here's my code:**

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            if (Console.ReadLine() == "cmds")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(cmds);
            }
            else if (Console.ReadLine() == "calculator")
            {
                    cal.ShowDialog();
            }
            else if (Console.ReadLine() == "cyan")
            {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
            }
            else if (Console.ReadLine() == "black")
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
            }
            else if (Console.ReadLine() == "clear")
            {
                Console.Clear();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Based on the comments under the answers I would like to cast doubt on your statement 'I am very experienced in C# Coding.'

Answer (score 6):

Store the results of your `Console.ReadLine` statement in a variable. This way you don't have to keep calling `Console.ReadLine`.

```
var cmd = Console.ReadLine();

if (cmd == "cmds")
{
    Console.WriteLine(cmds);
}
else if (cmd == "calculator")
{
   ...
```

The issue is essentially every time the `if` checks **each** condition its going to wait for more input

**Update** :

You will need to put it in a `loop`

```
string cmd = "";

while(cmd != "exit")
{
    cmd = Console.ReadLine();

    if (cmd == "cmds")
    {
         Console.WriteLine(cmds);
    }
    else if (cmd == "calculator")
    {
      ...
}
```

Comment: Still not working

Comment: @DavidT. updated

Comment: Still not working..

Comment: @DavidT. whats not working?

Comment: Use of unassigned local variable `cmd`

Comment: @DavidT.  Please see update, you need to make sure cmd is declared before the while

Comment: thanks for the help! +1

Comment: @DavidT. no problems

Comment: @DavidT. Hi if this has solved your problem dont forget to mark it as the correct answer, cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the good old switch statement. Gotta break it out every once in while! If/Else works just as well though. This will loop and check for the next line.

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

         while((string command = Console.ReadLine()) != null)
         {
               switch (command.ToUpper())
                {
                case "CMD":
                    Console.WriteLine("CMD");
                    break;
                case "CALCULATOR":
                     cal.ShowDialog();
                    break;
                default:
                   Console.WriteLine("Default");
                   break;
               }
           }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The name 'command' does not exit in the current context

Comment: You would have to set the default to break the while loop or break on a condition... i would use "return" - since the switch is using break.

Comment: If the solutions offered thus far.. do not solve your problem, you need to provide a bit more about what you want to do. As the answers thus far, DO solve the initial question

Comment: @DavidT.you may be using old version of C# which doesn't allow inline declaration. Try moving string command = null; before while statement and in while statement remove string before command.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Queue<string>` to keep a list of commands might not be a bad idea:

```
class Program
{
    static Queue<string> commandQueue = new Queue<string>(new[] {"FirstCommand", "SecondCommand", "ThirdCommand"});

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (Queue<string>.Enumerator enumerator = commandQueue.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Type in next command or type exit to close application");
                //this while is used to let user make as many mistakes as he/she wants.
                while (true)
                {
                    string command = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (command == "exit")
                    {
                        Environment.Exit(0);
                    }
                    //if typed command equals current command in queue ExecuteCommand and move queue to next one
                    if (command == enumerator.Current)
                    {
                        ExecuteCommand(command);
                        break;
                    }
                    else//Show error message
                    {
                        if (commandQueue.Contains(command))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Wrong command.");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Command not found.");
                        }
                    }
                } 
            }
            Console.WriteLine("We are done here, press enter to exit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    //Method that executes command according to its name
    static void ExecuteCommand(string commandName)
    {
        switch (commandName)
        {
            case "FirstCommand":
                Console.WriteLine("FirstCommand executed");
                break; 
            case "SecondCommand":
                Console.WriteLine("SecondCommand executed");
                break;
            case "ThirdCommand":
                Console.WriteLine("ThirdCommand executed");
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Command not found");
                break;
        }     
    }
}
```

Also if the requirement states that actions should performed in exact order it might not be a bad idea to just let the user press Enter to execute the next command instead of having to type its name.